# Не получается снизить скорость анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь снизить анимацию, никак не понимаю, как сделать чтобы она останавливалась не сразу а повремени:

Запускаю анимацию:

```
void Start() {
    anim.Play("name");
}
```

анимация крутится без остановки, начинаю снижать скорость:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
       anim["name"].speed-=5;
   }
}
```

Начинает смесь какая-то, то быстро, то медленно...
Как правильно менять скорость анимации?

Анимация имеет тип `Loop`, при этом крутится постоянно, как нужно, если поменять на другие типы, или по умолчанию, анимация проигрывается 1 раз и останавливается.

Comment: Покажите код, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @sanmai, не поверите, я показал, код. демонстрирующий проблему. Вы ожидали еще какой-то код? Это происходит вызов в `Start` методе.

Comment: @Nike возможно вам помогут корутины(coroutines).

Comment: @ArtikSlayer, причем тут корутины? Это для задержки. а у меня проблема со снижением скорости анимации.

Comment: Вы не показали код, демонстрирующий проблему, так как этот код нельзя запустить и увидеть проблему своими глазами. Нельзя увидеть, понимаете?

Comment: @sanmai, Если вы не разбираетесь в этом, то не нужно писать об этом. Проблема уже давно решена. И ответ уже дан. Вам не понятно до-сих-пор? Увы, ничем помочь не могу. Можете смело пройти мимо. Посмотрел ваши вопросы, о боже, вы прям много даете воспроизводимого кода, что не одного не увидел, только просите, дайте мне, дайте...

Comment: @Nike ваш вопрос бесполезен для этого сайта, так как мало кто другой, если вообще кто, сможет понять из этого вопроса и ответа в чём, собственно, была проблема. Такие вопросы следует закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, нельзя применять оператор `-=` или `+=` для анимаций, только `=`, решено было через `AnimationState`.

```
IEnumerator Speed() {
    for (float s = anim ["name"].speed; s >= 0; s -= 0.1f) {
        foreach (AnimationState state in anim) {
            state.speed = s;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.1f);
    }
}
```

Теперь скорость уменьшается правильно.

Comment: О, Боже! Что это? Корутины)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer, причем тут корутины? Я повторяю еще раз, корутины тут не причем. Они используются для задержки, а проблема была в анимации.